# What am I doing wrong here?~~Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm enrolled in a coding class at the moment and part of it involves using the Tkinter function of Python. Our assignment was to create a script that would show an "earth" rotating the "Sun". Really all this does is utilize basic geometric shapes and trigonometry (which was a pain in the butt to get to work), and as far as I can tell, my code *should* be working, but for whatever reason, it's continuing to ignore my if/elif statements. I get the feeling my confusion is due to some lack of experience and understanding, but I was hoping someone could lend me a hand in figuring out what I'm doing wrong with this. Thank you for reading. ^-^

```
#import Tkinter package responsible for constructing a
# graphical user interface, GUI

import Tkinter

#from Tkinter, import Canvas Class, which allows us to draw on the GUI
from Tkinter import Canvas, NW, Scale, HORIZONTAL
from math import cos, sin, radians


#create a child object called root. This object is our window. Tk() is 
#the class constructor to instantiate the window
root = Tkinter.Tk()

#call the method title passing in the title of our window
root.title("Earth Orbit")

#create a child object called canvas. This object is our canvas for
#drawing. We instantiate from the Canvas class, calling the constructor and
#passing in the parent of our canvas, and defining the dimenstions
canvas = Canvas(root,width=600,height=600,bg="white")

#call the grid method so that whatever we place on the canvas will be visible
canvas.grid()

color = canvas.create_polygon(0, 0, 0, 600, 600, 600, 600, 0, fill=
"light blue")
season = canvas.create_text(50,100,text="Winter", anchor=NW)
#intial coordinates for our circle
xpos = 275
ypos = 25

Earth = canvas.create_oval(xpos, ypos, xpos+25, ypos+25, fill="blue", outline="cyan")

x = cos(radians(0))
y = sin(radians(0))
Sun = canvas.create_oval(200, 200, 400, 400, fill="orange", outline="yellow")
def changeCirclePosition(event):
    x = 300 + (200*cos(radians(rectSlider.get())))
    y = 300 + (200*-sin(radians(rectSlider.get())))
    canvas.coords(Earth, x, y, x+25, y+25)
rectSlider = Scale(root,from_=0, to=360,orient=HORIZONTAL,label='Change Position',command=changeCirclePosition)    
canvas.create_window(250,500, anchor=NW, window=rectSlider)

if 0<= rectSlider < 90:
        canvas.itemconfigure(color, fill="green")
        canvas.itemconfigure(season,text="Spring")
elif 90<=rectSlider < 180:
        canvas.itemconfigure(color, fill="yellow")
        canvas.itemconfigure(season,text="Summer")
elif 180 <= rectSlider < 270:
        canvas.itemconfigure(color, fill="orange")
        canvas.itemconfigure(season,text="Autumn")
elif 270 <= rectSlider < 360:
        canvas.itemconfigure(color, fill="light blue")
        canvas.itemconfigure(season,text="Winter")
canvas.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Beware that there are not many people who are going to read through all that code, try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put those comparisons *inside* the callback. Also, you can't compare the `Scale` itself to an integer, you have to get its value, as you did for `x` and `y`:

```
def changeCirclePosition(event):
    x = 300 + (200*cos(radians(rectSlider.get())))
    y = 300 + (200*-sin(radians(rectSlider.get())))
    canvas.coords(Earth, x, y, x+25, y+25)
    if 0<= rectSlider.get() < 90:
            canvas.itemconfigure(color, fill="green")
            canvas.itemconfigure(season,text="Spring")
    elif ...
```